# What are the stats for an imp in ad&d 2nd edition ravenloft?

Tags: monsters, warlock, familiars, adnd-2e, ravenloft

While searching for a familiar in Ravenloft in AD&D 2e I rolled a 19 and found an imp, but I can't find the stat block for it. Where can I find it and what is it?

Comment: Found mention of it? In another book, or online somewhere perhaps?

Comment: There weren't warlocks in 2e--can I ask what you're indicating by putting that tag on the question? Also, are you playing one of the Ravenloft-named modules up-converted to 2e, a campaign in the 2e Ravenloft setting ("black box"), one of the 2e ravenloft-set modules (RA/RM/RQ series), or something else?

Comment: 2e had warlocks, it is the name used by male witches. The witch is a kit from the Complete Wizard's Handbook. At third level they got the "secure familiar" ability, which allowed them to call for familiars without the costly rituals of the "find familiar" spell.

Comment: Imp familiars are also mentioned in the CWH, yet, not in the regular list of familiars. So it would be useful if you could provide some information about the d20 roll. Is it the normal d20 roll from the PHB with 19-20 interpreted according to the Ravenloft Campaign Setting?

Comment: @ZwiQ good catch, thank you! (I even have the CWH sitting on the bookshelf next to me as I type this, I just haven't cracked it open in about two decades! Egg on my face....)

Answer (score 3):

The third Monstrous Compendium for Ravenloft, has a page referring DMs and players to other AD&D 2e products for the stats of various monsters. In the case of Imp, the stats are available in the Monstrous Compendium Volume 1. You can also find them in **TSR 2140, Monstrous Manual**.

> Imps are diminutive creatures of an evil nature who roam the world and act as familiars for lawful evil wizards and priests.

Imps can polymorph and appear as other animal familiars. They confer magic resistance and regeneration to their masters as long as they are within the telepathic range. They also increase the spellcasting level of their masters. For further details, I suggest obtaining a copy of the book.

---

<sub>[ You might also benefit from the following exchange: [Where can I find a complete index of all AD&D 2e monster entries compiled on to one site that is still up and functional at this point in time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144259/where-can-i-find-a-complete-index-of-all-add-2e-monster-entries-compiled-on-to) ]</sub>

<sub>PS: According to the Ravenloft Campaign Setting (red box), there is a 10% chance per level that a lawful evil wizard summons an imp when the *Find Familiar* spell is cast. Assuming that you are even a 1st level wizard, a roll of 19 in d20 could be that 10%.</sub>